# ASP.NET MVC4 redirecting without the context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a method IsUserLoggedIn(), and I want it to redirect the user to the Login page if the user isn't logged in (I.E if session has expired). Problem is I don't have a filterContext and It's not in a Controller, so how can I redirect, I don't really want to pass in any more parameters, like a controller instance or something. Is it possible?

Comment: This is already handled using Forms Authentication and `LoginUrl` in the configuration. Please explain your question more.

Comment: Forms Authentication? I'm not using any integrated User/Auth systems, I've written my own system. So can't use those..?

Comment: Writing something arbitrary and hoping it'll fit in the framework is not a very effective technique.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this in ASP.NET MVC is to have an Action Filter that does the check and redirects the user if they are not logged in. The default implementation of AuthorizeAttribute will redirect to the authentication/forms/loginUrl specified in the web.config but you can always implement your own attribute derived from the default AuthorizeAttribute and redirect to wherever you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you follow conventions and standards of the framework, use this:
regardless of where you are in your context the following should take care of your problem. In your web.config there must be a section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Having that by definition will redirect user to login page and the timeout (in minutes) until cookies expire. More about authentication [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx).

But if you have your own system, you won't find any help here, since nobody knows anything about it, but yourself. :)

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi. was it of any help at all? Thanks.